# Dependency Property not set from style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

I'm trying to synchronize scrolling between two datagrids so that each scroll is mirrored between them (either horizontal or vertical scrolling), after googling around how to do I started to implement my method but the setter call from my scrollbar style never calls the dependency object to set the value.

This is my data grid.

```
<dataGridEx:DataGridEx ColumnHeaders="{Binding SystemMonitorValues.ColumnHeaders}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding SystemMonitorValues.Rows}"
                       Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
                       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                       ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <dataGridEx:DataGridEx.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="scroll:ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup" Value="Group1" />
        </Style>
    </dataGridEx:DataGridEx.Resources>
</dataGridEx:DataGridEx>
```

So within the scroll bar style I am attempting to set the `ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup` to have the value "Group1".

My `ScrollSynchronizer` is setup as follows:

```
public class ScrollSynchronizer : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollGroupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(@"ScrollGroup",
            typeof(string), typeof(ScrollSynchronizer), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScrollGroupChanged)));

static ScrollSynchronizer()
{
}

public string ScrollGroup
{
    get
    {
        return (string)this.GetValue(ScrollGroupProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetValue(ScrollGroupProperty, value);
    }
}

private static void OnScrollGroupChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = d as System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer;

    ...
}
```

I'm placing a breakpoint within the `OnScrollGroupChanged` method which is the `PropertyChangedCallback` for the `DependencyProperty` but for some reason this is never hit.

I know the style is working as the background of the scrollbar is being set to `Red` but the setter for the `ScrollGroup` doesn't seem to want to be called, this is also shown in Snoop in that the Style is correctly set with the two setters and even the setter for the `ScrollSynchronizer` point's to the correct object.

I'm simply at a loss to why this is not being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup` should be an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of a regular dependency property:

```
public static class ScrollSynchronizer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollGroupProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ScrollGroup", typeof(string), typeof(ScrollSynchronizer),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollGroupChanged));

    public static string GetScrollGroup(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ScrollGroupProperty);
    }

    public static void SetScrollGroup(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ScrollGroupProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnScrollGroupChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollBar = d as ScrollBar;
        ...
    }
}
```

Note also that the DependencyObject parameter of the PropertyChangedCallback is of type `ScrollBar` when you set the property in a ScrollBar Style.

Comment: Yup, completely missed that. I thought I had missed something when setting up the `DependencyProperty`. Thank you.